# Difficulty with json string deserialization

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I  make a web request in `Silverlight` for windows phone. And this is the responce.

```
{"result": {
"account": null,
"checkInfo": null,
"command": null,
"shifts": [
    {
        "description": "17:45 - 17:55 work shift",
        "id": 5459,
        "venueId": 132
    }]}}
```

I use `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` and my purpose is to catch the array - shifts.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(StringShifts);
JArray sh = (JArray)obj["shifts"];
```

But every time `sh` value is `null`. What i'm i doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that the exact response?  I ask as you are missing a closing curly brace on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way around is: (This is very helpful, if you are doing more operations like this in your project)
Create these classes in your project

```
public class Shift
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int venueId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public object account { get; set; }
        public object checkInfo { get; set; }
        public object command { get; set; }
        public List<Shift> shifts { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }
```

And then in your code

```
 var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(StringShifts);
 foreach(var shift in rootObject.result.shifts)
 {
     Console.Write(shift.description);
 }
```

This way you can have more control on your json response data. But L.B 's answer if it is one time process in your app.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var shift in obj["result"]["shifts"])
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)shift["description"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the root `results` node; this is how you should use it:

```
JArray sh = (JArray)obj["result"]["shifts"];
```

Also, do note that there is a missing `}` in the end of your JSON sample above!

Comment: I made a small mistake, it is "result" and not "results"; please try it now!